# How do I add the Timer of the game?

Tags: java, timer

My friends and i are creating a gme like bejeweled. it is almost over, but we have some problems.  We couldn't add Timer to game. for example, we want to that level 1 finished after 2 minutes. How can we do?

```
//in this class, we created game area etc.
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Level1 extends JFrame {

private JPanel anaPanel, p1;
private JPanel grid;
public String comand;
public static JButton[] buttons;
public String imgName;
public Color c1, c2;
public String score=ButtonActionListener.str;

public Level1() {

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x= ((dim.width-960)/2);
    int y= ((dim.height-640)/2);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(x, y, 960,640);
    anaPanel = new JPanel();
    anaPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    p1=new JPanel();

    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img//sol.png"));      
    c1 = new Color(21,120,227);
    c2 = new Color(250,215,1);

    grid=new JPanel();


    grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8,5,5)); 
    grid.setBounds(5, 5, 460, 640);
    buttons = new JButton[64];


 //Creating random image for buttons
    ActionListener buttonActionListener = new ButtonActionListener();
        for (int i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {

                Random r = new Random();
                int a = r.nextInt(7)+1;

                switch(a){
                case 1 : buttons[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("img//Cakal.png"));
                        break;
                case 2 : buttons[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("img//BugsBunny.png"));
                        break;
                case 3 : buttons[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("img//Pig.png"));
                        break;
                case 4 : buttons[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("img//Taz.png"));
                        break;
                case 5 : buttons[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("img//Sam.png"));
                        break;
                case 6 : buttons[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("img//DuffyDuck.png"));
                        break;
                case 7 : buttons[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("img//Tweety.png"));
                        break;
                /*case 8 : buttons[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("img//Slyvester.png"));
                        break;
                case 9 : buttons[i]=new JButton(new ImageIcon("img//RoadRunner.png"));
                        break;*/
                }

                buttons[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
                buttons[i].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                buttons[i].setFocusable(true);
                buttons[i].setOpaque(true);
                buttons[i].setBackground(c1);

                //Adding number to find easily
                comand=Integer.toString(i);

                //Get ImageIcon name
                imgName=((ImageIcon)buttons[i].getIcon()).toString();

                buttons[i].addActionListener(buttonActionListener);
                buttons[i].setActionCommand(comand);

                grid.add(buttons[i]);

          }
        grid.setBackground(c1);
        p1.add(background);
        p1.setBackground(c1);
        anaPanel.add(p1);
        anaPanel.add(grid);
        add(anaPanel);   




}


static JButton[] getButton(){
    return buttons;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Level1 l=new Level1();
    l.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

In this class, there are algorithms of game.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public JButton previousButton = null;
    public int numP, numC;
    public JButton[] buttons=Level1.getButton();
    public int score=0;
    public static String str;


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JButton currentButton = (JButton)e.getSource();

    if (previousButton == null) {
        previousButton = currentButton;
        return;
    }

    int numP=Integer.parseInt(((JButton)previousButton).getActionCommand());
    int numC=Integer.parseInt(((JButton)currentButton).getActionCommand());

    if (numP==(numC+1) || numP==(numC-1) || numP==(numC+8) || numP==(numC-8) ){
        Icon previousIcon = previousButton.getIcon();
        Icon currentIcon = currentButton.getIcon();
        currentButton.setIcon(previousIcon);
        previousButton.setIcon(currentIcon);
        previousButton = null;

    }
    else
        previousButton=null;
    startAnimation();
}

    private void startAnimation()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                runAnimation();
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private int d;
    private int e;

    private void runAnimation()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        a = r.nextInt(64);
        b = r.nextInt(64);
        c = r.nextInt(64);
        d = r.nextInt(64);
        e = r.nextInt(64);

        for(int i=0; i<63; i++)
        {
            final int iFinal = i;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    doAnimationStep(iFinal);
                }
            });

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void doAnimationStep(int i)
    {
        String s0 = buttons[i].getIcon().toString();
        String s1 = buttons[i+1].getIcon().toString();
        String s2 = buttons[i+2].getIcon().toString();
        String s3 = buttons[i+3].getIcon().toString();
        String s4 = buttons[i+4].getIcon().toString();

        if(s0.equals(s1) && s1.equals(s2) && s2.equals(s3) && s3.equals(s4)){

            if(i > 7){

                for(int j = i; j > 0; j=j-8){
                    if(j > 7){
                        buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+1].setIcon(buttons[j-7].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+2].setIcon(buttons[j-6].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+3].setIcon(buttons[j-5].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+4].setIcon(buttons[j-4].getIcon());
                        score+=100;
                        str=String.valueOf(score);
                    }
                    else{
                        buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+1].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+2].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+3].setIcon(buttons[d].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+4].setIcon(buttons[e].getIcon());
                        score+=100;
                        str=String.valueOf(score);
                    }

                }
            }
            else{
                buttons[i].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                buttons[i+1].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                buttons[i+2].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                buttons[i+3].setIcon(buttons[d].getIcon());
                buttons[i+4].setIcon(buttons[e].getIcon());
                score+=100;
                str=String.valueOf(score);
            }

        }else{

        if(s0.equals(s1) && s1.equals(s2) && s2.equals(s3)){

            if(i > 7){

                for(int j = i; j > 0; j=j-8){
                    if(j > 7){
                        buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+1].setIcon(buttons[j-7].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+2].setIcon(buttons[j-6].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+3].setIcon(buttons[j-5].getIcon());
                        score+=100;
                        str=String.valueOf(score);
                    }
                    else{
                        buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+1].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+2].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+3].setIcon(buttons[d].getIcon());
                        score+=100;
                        str=String.valueOf(score);
                    }


                }
            }
            else{
                buttons[i].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                buttons[i+1].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                buttons[i+2].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                buttons[i+3].setIcon(buttons[d].getIcon());
                score+=100;
                str=String.valueOf(score);
            }


        }else{

        if(s0.equals(s1) && s1.equals(s2))
        {

            if(i > 7){

                for(int j = i; j > 0; j=j-8){
                    if(j > 7){
                        buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+1].setIcon(buttons[j-7].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+2].setIcon(buttons[j-6].getIcon());
                        score+=100;
                        str=String.valueOf(score);
                    }
                    else{
                        buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+1].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                        buttons[j+2].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                        score+=100;
                        str=String.valueOf(score);
                    }

                }
            }
            else{
                buttons[i].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                buttons[i+1].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                buttons[i+2].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                score+=100;
                str=String.valueOf(score);
            }

        }
        if(i < 48){
            String v0 = buttons[i].getIcon().toString();
            String v1 = buttons[i+8].getIcon().toString();
            String v2 = buttons[i+16].getIcon().toString();

            if(v0.equals(v1) && v1.equals(v2)) {  
                if(i > 23){

                    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j=j-8){
                        if(j > 23){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[j-24].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[j-16].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());
                            score+=100;
                            str=String.valueOf(score);
                        }
                        else if(j > 15){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[j-16].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());
                            score+=100;
                            str=String.valueOf(score);

                        }
                        else if(j > 7){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());

                        }
                        else{
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(i > 15){

                    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j=j-8){
                        if(j > 15){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[j-16].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());

                        }
                        else if(j > 7){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());

                        }
                        else{
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                        }
                    }

                }
                else if(i > 7){

                    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j=j-8){
                        if(j > 7){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());

                        }
                        else{
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                        }
                    }

                }
                else{
                    buttons[i].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                    buttons[i+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                    buttons[i+16].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());

                }
            }
        }else{

            String v0 = buttons[i-16].getIcon().toString();
            String v1 = buttons[i-8].getIcon().toString();
            String v2 = buttons[i].getIcon().toString();

            if(v0.equals(v1) && v1.equals(v2)) {  
                if(i > 23){

                    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j=j-8){
                        if(j > 23){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[j-24].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[j-16].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());
                        }
                        else if(j > 15){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[j-16].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());

                        }
                        else if(j > 7){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());

                        }
                        else{
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(i > 15){

                    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j=j-8){
                        if(j > 15){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[j-16].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());

                        }
                        else if(j > 7){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());

                        }
                        else{
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                        }
                    }

                }
                else if(i > 7){

                    for(int j = i; j >= 0; j=j-8){
                        if(j > 7){
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[j-8].getIcon());

                        }
                        else{
                            buttons[j].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                            buttons[j+16].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());
                        }
                    }

                }
                else{
                    buttons[i].setIcon(buttons[a].getIcon());
                    buttons[i+8].setIcon(buttons[b].getIcon());
                    buttons[i+16].setIcon(buttons[c].getIcon());

                }
            }

        }
        }
        }
    }
    public String getScore(){
        return str;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into [swing timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

It's easy to implement and should be enough for your purpose.

You could make it count down the time for user, and at the end, stop the level (let the player retry etc.).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Timer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) with it's [schedule()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29) method.

On callback simple call the methods to "end your level".

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int j = 0 ; j <60 ; j++)
{
    delayer (1000);
    counter++;
}

if (counter == 60)
{
    // put what you want to happen after 60 seconds here
}
```

and then have a delayer method:

```
private static void delayer (long milliseconds)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep (1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
    }
}
```